# resize "shrink" an .img file from the command line

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, parted

## Shrink an .img file from the command line

I need to be able to shrink the .img for use on other drives.  I can do this using `gparted`, but do not always have a GUI, so I want to translate the `gparted` step below into `parted`

to be verbose, here is my whole proceedure using `gparted`

### insert sd card

```bash
$ lsblk
```

### copy image

```bash
$ sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=rp4-ubuntu-server-22.04-fresh.img status=progress oflag=sync
```

### create a loopback device

```bash
$ sudo losetup -f
$ sudo losetup /dev/loop0 /home/phil/dl/rp4-ubuntu-server-22.04-fresh.img
$ sudo partprobe /dev/loop0
```

### resize the partition (This is where I need help!)

```bash
$ sudo gparted /dev/loop0
```

resize --> drag to desired size --> apply --> exit `gparted`

### done with the loopback device

```bash
$ sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

### find last sector

```bash
$ fdisk -l /home/phil/dl/rp4-ubuntu-server-22.04-fresh.img
```

```bash
   Disk /home/phil/dl/rp4-ubuntu-server-22.04-fresh.img: 59.63 GiB, 64021856256 bytes,
125042688 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disklabel type: dos
   Disk identifier: 0x1b140081

   Device                                           Boot  Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
   /home/phil/dl/rp4-ubuntu-server-22.04-fresh.img1 *      2048  526335  524288  256M
c W95 FAT32
   /home/phil/dl/rp4-ubuntu-server-22.04-fresh.img2      526336 7739391 7213056  3.4G 83 Linux
```

### resize the .img

```bash
$ sudo truncate --size=$[(7739391+1)*512] /home/phil/dl/rp4-ubuntu-server-22.04-fresh.img
```

Can you show me how to accomplish the `gparted` step using cli `parted`?

Comment: Try this -> https://askubuntu.com/a/1390007 I think is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here is the way I am doing it.

Assuming the data presented in your post, this should do the trick:
Entering the parted app to resize the desired partiton:

```
parted /dev/loop0
```

checking for the current state:

```
print
```

Assuming you want the second partition for resizing - and that you want the second partition to "end" on the "7739391" sector, you can resize the desired partition with "resizepart" (inside the "parted" CLI):

```
resizepart 2 7739391s
```

You can check again with `print`. If everything is ok, save it and exit parted with

```
quit
```

The usual warning - please backup any important data before doing stuff like this, yada, yada, yada :) ...
Have a nice day